# html button checkbox onchange event doesn't get triggered on iOS 14 when unticking checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I have a website temporarily running on [droneard.de](http://droneard.de) which includes a CSS menu (taken from https://codepen.io/omar_anwari_/pen/WdBgBg). This solution uses an invisible checkbox. Now I trigger a JS-function to change the opacity of my content wrapper to make the text better readable by using the onchange event at my button. In the JS-function I set a variable to the current opacity and use it to set/animate the opacity to 0.6 if it's 1 and to 1 if it's 0.6 .
This works great on all modern browsers, but on Safari on iOS 14.8 and on macOS Big Sur I'm having the problem, that it perfectly loses it's capacity if I tick the checkbox/open the menu, but it doesn't set it back to opacity: 1 when closing the menu / unticking the checkbox. I don't think that the problem is in JavaScript, is it possible that Safari doesn't see the unticking as an "onchange" event?

JavaScript:

```
function menubackground () {
  var opa_city__var_from_home = $('.fadeinobject').css('opacity');
  if (opa_city__var_from_home == '0.6') {
    $(".fadeinobject").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 230);
  }
  else {
    $(".fadeinobject").animate({"opacity": "0.6"}, 230);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="menubackground()" />
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me. Lots of websites use the `change` event on checkboxes, and they can't all be broken on IOS 14.

Comment: Add a `console.log()` call, and check if you see the message in the web console in Big Sur.

Comment: I think it's more likely that the problem is with `('.fadeinobject').css('opacity')`

Comment: Instead of using `.css()`, use a class that has an opacity transition, and add/remove the class.

Comment: thanks, I'm a beginner and this was already quite helpful. On newer versions the variable is 1 or 0.6, on macOS Big Sur it is 1 or 0.6000000001234 or something. Do you have a quick solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opacity is stored internally as a floating point number, and this introduces possible errors. So format the number with a single decimal place before comparing.

```js
function menubackground () {
  var opa_city__var_from_home = $('.fadeinobject').css('opacity');
  if (parseFloat(opa_city__var_from_home).toFixed(1) == '0.6') {
    $(".fadeinobject").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 230);
  }
  else {
    $(".fadeinobject").animate({"opacity": "0.6"}, 230);
  }
}
```